# I am using ssis and I am getting this error "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint .Cannot insert duplicate key in object . The duplicate key value is

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am new to SSIS and I am getting an error message . Can anyone help me ? There are not duplicates in my data

The error message is 
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E2F  Description: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_DimCourse'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.DimCourse'. The duplicate key value is (CS1301).".

My current table looks like this

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DimCourse](
    [CourseCode] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [SubjectCode] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [CourseNumber] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [CourseTitle] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Level1] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Level2] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DimCourse] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CourseCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory you are trying to insert duplicate values into your primary key column `CourseCode`

Comment: There are no duplicates

Comment: @Nick are you sure you aren't dealing with duplicates.  you have to think about values that exists in your table AND values you are tyring to insert into your table.  So if your ssis uses a query as a source are you sure rows didn't get duplicated by a join condition or something.  Or that perhaps CS1301 exists in the destination table AND the source table which is trying to insert it?  The error has only 1 meaning that there is duplicate data.

Comment: As @M.Ali commented above, the message is pretty self explanatory. Your data (target table) won't have duplicates obviously because there's a primary key constraint. . The problem is that you're trying to insert a record (source data) which the primary key already exists in the target. Check your source data and I'm pretty sure you'll find a CourseCode which already exists in the target. A good way to test this is to write the output of your ssis job to a text file then check exactly what the job is trying to insert in the table.

Answer (score 5):

I know I am too late to answer. I was getting the similar error message, found out what was the problem, and solved it. I hope it will help the future readers.

**Scenario:**

1. I have a source table with dbo.Codes with primary key
   combination(CodeID, CodeName).
2. In order to create my destination
   table, I have used the SQL Server-->Database-->Tasks-->Generate
   Scripts, option.
3. Then, in the SSIS package, I simply used the OLE DB
   Source and OLE DB Destination element. It was returning
   error: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'pkCodes'. Cannot insert
   duplicate key in object 'dbo.Codes'. The duplicate key value is
   (106, da7A).".

**What I have tried to solve:**

1. I have tried to use the sql command as source: `Select CodeID, CodeName from dbo.Codes GROUP BY CodeID, CodeName`. It was still returning error. I got confused at this point.
2. After searching online, I found a tips to add a SSIS Toolbox-->Common-->Sort element between OLE DB Source and OLE DB Destination. I checked the option "Remove rows with duplicate sort values" in the Sort element. I was still getting error.
3. Then, I had enabled the data viewer between OLE DB Source and Sort element. I could see there are two rows: 106, da7a and 106, da7A in the source table.

**What is the real problem?**

My source table coulmn CodeName is case sensitive but my CodeName column in the destination table is not case sensitive. This has occured because, sql server generate script option, Script Collation is set to false by default.

**Solution that worked for me:**

I recreated my destination table with Script Collation option: True, which made my destination column case sensitive and it has solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

A record with CourseCode = 'CS1301' already exists in the target and the same CourseCode will be inserted by SSIS from the source which leads to a duplicate.

Either that or your target does not contain CourseCode = 'CS1301' yet, but your source data contains two rows both with the same CourseCode. By inserting the duplicate into the target environment will also lead to a duplicate.

I would suggest querying your source data for CourseCode = 'CS1301' to see if you find two rows. If there is only one row, query your target data for CourseCode = 'CS1301'. If there is also one row, compare and depending on the situation you probably have to delete one of them.

Answer (score 0):

While on the production server a "perfectly good" package can fail days, weeks, or months later with a false duplicate primary key error. In my experience this happens when a package has the development standard which is something like EncryptWithUserKey. This can be avoided by following [MS Standard practice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/security/access-control-for-sensitive-data-in-packages?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16) by encrypting the package, (or perhaps setting as do not save sensitive date which I didn't bother trying). It is also good practice to parameterize connections (configure connection manager dynamically).